# Handlebars #each syntax is giving me problems

Tags: handlebars.js

The code inside `{{#foods}}` doesn't work and I don't know what to do.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="options">
        {{#meal}}
            <h3>Select the food you want to add to {{name}}</h3>
            <div class="options-items">
                {{#foods}}
                    <a class="test" href="http://localhost:8000/dashboard/add/{{meal.id}}">
                        {{foods.name}}
                    </a>
                {{/foods}}
            </div>
        {{/meal}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my context data:

```
{
"meal":
    [{
        "id":2,
        "name":"Lunch"
    }],
"foods":
    [{
        "id":1,
        "name":"Banana",
        "kcal":89,
        "carb":22.84,
        "prot":1.09,
        "fats":0.33
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Chicken",
        "kcal":144,
        "carb":0,
        "prot":21,
        "fats":2.6
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Milk",
        "kcal":47,
        "carb":4.9,
        "prot":3.3,
        "fats":1.6
    }]
}
```

Comment: It will help others to help you if you share the shape of your data. ie., Please post the data you are passing to your template function.

Comment: One thing I _can_ see is that `{{foods.name}}` will not work. This should be just `{{name}}`, just as you have done above for the meal name. This is because `name` is a property of each food, not the `foods` colleciton.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

First, `foods` is a sibling of `meal` in your data. Handlebars is context-aware. The way you have `{{#foods}}` nested under `{{#meal}}` tells Handlebars to look for `foods` as a property of each `meal`. This is incorrect. We need to use a "path" to tell Handlebars to step-up a level. The path won't play nicely with your `{{#foods}}` syntax, so I am going to use the more conventional `{{#each}}`. The template becomes:

```
{{#each ../foods}}
  <a class="test" href="http://localhost:8000/dashboard/add/{{meal.id}}">{{foods.name}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

Second, as I mentioned in the comment, `name` is not a property of the `foods` array. Instead, you should just use `{{name}}` to reference the `name` of the currently iterated item from the `foods` array.
Now our template becomes:

```
{{#each ../foods}}
  <a class="test" href="http://localhost:8000/dashboard/add/{{meal.id}}">{{name}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

Third, `{{meal.id}}` will not work. As I mentioned above, Handlebars is context-aware. This means that when it is within the `{{#each foods}}` loop, the `{{meal.id}}` is telling Handlebars to find the `id` of a `meal` object belonging to the currently iterated item in `foods`. Instead, we will need to use a path again to get back to the "meal-level" of our template execution:

```
{{#each ../foods}}
  <a class="test" href="http://localhost:8000/dashboard/add/{{../id}}">{{name}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/8o71jpyd/) for reference.

Comment: @Pau Please let me know if this solution works for you.